# Como utilizar um nome customizável para o campo de senha no Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, auth, laravel-8

Já tentei de tudo, mas nada funciona. Eu tenho quase certeza que o motivo é que o nome padrão do attempt "password" não condiz com a o nome da coluna passwordhash,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request){
        $data =  $request->all();
        

        if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['login'=>$data['loginadmin'],'password'=>$data['passadmin'],'isadmin'=>1]))
        {
            return 'logou';
        }else{
            return 'naao logou';
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Meu Model User:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User
{
    protected $table = "tb_user";
    protected $fillable = [
        'login',
        'passwordhash',
        'fullname',
        'cpf'
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    
}
```

Eu creio que vou precisar mudar esse padrão do Attempt "password" pra passwordhash, mas não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer. Ou pode até ser outra solução e eu não qual.

Desde já agradeço quem me ajudar.

Comment: voce ja tentou alterar a chave de array de `passsword` para `passwordhash` no método `attempt`?

Comment: pior que já tentei, mas quando faço isso da um erro q o atributo password está null, ou seja, é obrigatório usar desse jeito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa sobrescrever o método `getAuthPassword` no seu model de `User`  para que ele retorne o atributo `passwordhash`, veja:

```
class User extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User
{
    protected $table = "tb_user";
    protected $fillable = [
        'login',
        'passwordhash',
        'fullname',
        'cpf'
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;
    

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->passwordhash;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara ajudou demaiss, só foi implementar que deu certo, obrigado mesmo.

Comment: O campo password está cadastrado "senha" no meu banco de dados. Eu tentei fazer com essa função mas não deu certo. Alguma outra ideia? Obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Eu tentaria olhar na trait AuthenticateUsers, na função validateLogin, trocar na validação o 'password' pelo 'passwordhash', talvez o erro seja nessa validação que está dando o return false.